# aes-128 refers to the block size, key or both

Tags: ciphers

What does the number used in cipher suites next to the symmetric encryption algorithm reefers to?  Does it mean each block is divided into 128 bit blocks, the key size or both ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard):

> AES is a variant of Rijndael which has a **fixed block size of 128 bits**, and a **key size of 128, 192, or 256 bits**.

Thus, the number in AES-128, AES-192 and AES-256 refers to the key size only.